How to Determine the Velocity Distribution of Ions After Ion Channel Opens Based on Electrodiffusion Theory?
I am currently studying the behavior of ions as they move across a cell membrane after the opening of ion channels. I understand that electrodiffusion theory provides a framework for analyzing this, specifically through the Nernst-Planck equation, which combines diffusion and electromigration effects.
My primary question is: How can I determine the velocity distribution of ions (such as Na⁺, K⁺) across the membrane after the ion channels open?
Here is what I’ve gathered so far:

Electrodiffusion Theory suggests that ion movement is governed by both concentration gradients and the electric field across the membrane.
The Nernst-Planck equation provides a way to calculate ion flux $\vec J (\vec r)$ as a function of diffusion and the electric potential gradient. However, this equation primarily gives the flux and not the velocity distribution of individual ions.
Given that the ion velocity $\vec v$ is related to the flux and concentration through the equation:
$$
\vec J= c\cdot \vec v
$$
and knowing that the drift velocity of ions under an electric field
$\vec E$ can be expressed as:
$$
\vec v_{\text{drift}} = \mu \vec E
$$
where $\mu$ is the ion’s mobility. So,


What additional steps or assumptions are needed to accurately compute the full velocity distribution of ions in this scenario?
How would factors like ion collisions, interaction with the membrane structure, and local variations in electric potential affect the velocity distribution?

Any insights on the application of electrodiffusion theory or other related models to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Are there any related papers?
